# Windows rails installation failing, currently on websocket mask compilation -- `make: *** [Makefile:246: websocket_mask.o]`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gcc, rubygems

I have tried a bunch of different ways to get Rails to install and haven't been able to find one that works. I have refrained from going the WSL way because my OS drive is nearly at capacity, but I plan to try that if I can't find a solution here.

With my current setup, I am failing on the compilation of `websocket_mask.c`.

Current process I took was one directed by John Elder to use `RailsInstaller` to get a bunch of the dependencies, then upgrade Ruby and Devkit from https://rubyinstaller.org/, then `gem install rails` to upgrade to the latest version of Rails.

When I ran `gem install rails`, I encountered an error I'd seen before in `make: gcc: No such file or directory` .

```
current directory: C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.5/ext/websocket-driver
make DESTDIR\=
generating websocket_mask-x64-mingw-ucrt.def
compiling websocket_mask.c
make: gcc: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:246: websocket_mask.o] Error 127

make failed, exit code 2
```

I followed [this](https://dev.to/gamegods3/how-to-install-gcc-in-windows-10-the-easier-way-422j) guide on installing `gcc` on windows. I ran `gem install rails` again and now have

```
current directory: C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.5/ext/websocket-driver
make DESTDIR\=
generating websocket_mask-x64-mingw-ucrt.def
compiling websocket_mask.c
websocket_mask.c:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
 #include <ruby.h>

make: *** [Makefile:246: websocket_mask.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

I could have sworn in a past attempt that I got past this point and was able to install Rails and proceed to errors in `rails new`, but I think it's possible this error had appeared above some other success messages and I proceeded. `rails -v` produces the most current version even with an error in installation.

I think it's all tied to this error in installing rails, but I remember in the past that `rails new` threw errors related to `msgpack` at one point and `sprockets-rails` at another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This morning, I got the same error when I installed RubyInstaller Ruby+Devkit 3.1.1-1 (x64).

I decided to install the version older RubyInstaller version Ruby+Devkit 3.0.3-1 (x64) for Windows 10, and I did not see this error anymore.

Comment: This works for me as well. I suppose we'll stick with an older version!